# To call function on onclick event based on condition using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code i have a checkbox on onclick event i want to check condition if it is check it should call check function if it is unchecked it should call remove function using single line if statement in onclick.Pls help me to do this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkProjectID"  value="test" name="Rowcheck"   onclick="Check()";"remove()"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

In jquery

```
$("#chkProjectID").click(function() {
  $(this).is(":checked") ? Check() : remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Example : http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/
The .checked property of a checkbox DOM element will tell give you the checked state of the element.

```
if(document.getElementById('isAgeSelected').checked) {
$("#txtAge").show();
} else {
$("#txtAge").hide();
}
```

However, there's a much prettier way to do this, using toggle:

```
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function () {
$("#txtAge").toggle(this.checked);
});

<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Age is something</div>​
```